# Unable to run React Native's Android project on MacOS

Tags: android, macos, react-native

I just started to learn React Native. 
Once I run "react-native run-android", I got this error

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find support-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-vector-drawable/27.1.1/support-vector-drawable-27.1.1.aar
> Could not find livedata-core.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/livedata-core/1.1.0/livedata-core-1.1.0.aar
> Could not find viewmodel.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/viewmodel/1.1.0/viewmodel-1.1.0.aar
> Could not find runtime.aar (android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/runtime/1.1.0/runtime-1.1.0.aar
```

this is my environment:

```
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14
      CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4278U CPU @ 2.60GHz
      Memory: 166.70 MB / 8.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 8.9.4 - /usr/local/bin/node
      npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.0, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.0, watchOS 5.0
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
      Xcode: 10.0/10A255 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.6.0-alpha.8af6728 => 16.6.0-alpha.8af6728 
      react-native: 0.57.3 => 0.57.3 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

[I tried open in Android Studio and same issue happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DwxA.png)

Answer (score 2):

I revoke my answer. I no longer want to support this site.

Comment: Ya, I did the same thing with different approach. I did suspect it was the something to do with build gradle file. What I did is create a sample project and match with my react native project.